# Brainfuck-to-C compiler written in C++

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, brainfuck, portability

This compiler, implemented in C++, takes brainfuck code and produces a valid (but still obfuscated) C program, which in turn can be compiled to a native binary.

Expected usage is as follows:

1. Build the compiler

   ```
   $ c++ -o bfc bfc.cpp
   ```
2. Compile a brainfuck program ([example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39252/9357)) to C

   ```
   $ ./bfc ascii.bf
   ```
3. Compile the resulting C program to an executable.

   ```
   $ cc -g -O0 -o ascii ascii.bf.c
   ```
4. Run the executable natively.

   ```
   $ ./ascii
   ```

   Or, you can also run it in a debugger.  As long as you compiled with debugging symbols included and without optimizations, you should be able to step through the brainfuck source code line by line.

   ```
   $ gdb ascii
   [...]
   (gdb) break ascii.bf:1
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000010fc: file ascii.bf, line 1.
   (gdb) run
   [...]
   Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffbd0) at ascii2.bf:1
   1   [-][
   (gdb) break ascii.bf:66
   Breakpoint 2 at 0x1000031c3: file ascii.bf, line 66.
   (gdb) cont
   Continuing.

   Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffbd0) at ascii.bf:66
   66      >>>>> >>>>> >>> .                   (c_ascii)
   (gdb) display m.ptr
   1: m.ptr = 4
   Current language:  auto; currently minimal
   (gdb) display /d m.mem[0] @ 32
   2: /d m.mem[0] @ 32 = {0, 58, 32, 10, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 58, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 58, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 58, 48, 0, 0}
   (gdb) display /d m.mem[m.ptr]
   3: /d m.mem[m.ptr] = 0
   ```

I'd like to know:

1. How well does this technique work for debuggers other than GDB?
2. Is there anything I should do to make either the compiler source code or the generated output more readable?
3. How should I improve the error handling?
4. Are there any other improvements you might suggest?

```
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static const char BOILERPLATE_HEAD[] = "\
#include <stdio.h>\n\
#include <stdlib.h>\n\
#include <strings.h>\n\
\n\
typedef unsigned char bf_mem_t;\n\
\n\
struct machine_state {\n\
    int ptr;\n\
    int size;\n\
    bf_mem_t *mem;\n\
};\n\
\n\
void error(int line, struct machine_state *m) __attribute__((noreturn));\n\
void error(int line, struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    abort();\n\
}\n\
\n\
int init_machine(struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    m->ptr = 0;\n\
    m->size = 8;\n\
    m->mem = calloc(m->size, sizeof(bf_mem_t));\n\
    return 0 != m->mem;\n\
}\n\
\n\
int realloc_machine(int line, struct machine_state *m, int min_size) {\n\
    int new_size = m->size;\n\
    do {\n\
        new_size <<= 1;\n\
    } while (new_size < min_size);\n\
    if (NULL == (m->mem = realloc(m->mem, new_size))) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    }\n\
    bzero(m->mem + m->size, new_size - m->size);\n\
    m->size = new_size;\n\
    return 1;\n\
}\n\
\n\
void advance(int line, struct machine_state *m, int change) {\n\
    m->ptr += change;\n\
}\n\
\n\
int ensure(int line, struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    if (m->ptr < 0) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    }\n\
    if (m->ptr >= m->size && !realloc_machine(line, m, m->ptr)) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    }\n\
    return 1;\n\
}\n\
\n\
int incr(int line, struct machine_state *m, int change) {\n\
    if (!ensure(line, m)) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    }\n\
    m->mem[m->ptr] += change;\n\
    return 1;\n\
}\n\
\n\
bf_mem_t mem(int line, struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    if (m->ptr < 0) {\n\
        error(line, m);\n\
    } else if (m->ptr >= m->size) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    } else {\n\
        return m->mem[m->ptr];\n\
    }\n\
}\n\
\n\
/* Only useful as a possible debugging breakpoint */\n\
struct machine_state *beginwhile(struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    return m;\n\
}\n\
\n\
/* Only useful as a possible debugging breakpoint */\n\
struct machine_state *endwhile(struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    return m;\n\
}\n\
\n\
int input(int line, struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    if (!ensure(line, m)) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    }\n\
    int c = getchar();\n\
    if (-1 == c) {\n\
        return 0;\n\
    } else {\n\
        m->mem[m->ptr] = c;\n\
        return 1;\n\
    }\n\
}\n\
\n\
void output(int line, struct machine_state *m) {\n\
    putchar(mem(line, m));\n\
}\n\
void comment(int line, struct machine_state *m, const char *comment) {\n\
    return;\n\
    fprintf(stderr, \"%d %s\", line, comment);\n\
}\n\
\n\
#define L       advance(__LINE__, &m, -1);\n\
#define R       advance(__LINE__, &m, +1);\n\
#define M       if (!incr(__LINE__, &m, -1)) error(__LINE__, &m);\n\
#define P       if (!incr(__LINE__, &m, +1)) error(__LINE__, &m);\n\
#define W       while(mem(__LINE__, beginwhile(&m)))\n\
#define E       endwhile(&m);\n\
#define I       if (!input(__LINE__, &m)) error(__LINE__, &m);\n\
#define O       output(__LINE__, &m);\n\
#define C(x)    comment(__LINE__, &m, (x));\n\
\n\
\n\
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\n\
    struct machine_state m;\n\
    init_machine(&m);\n"
"#line 1 ";

static const char BOILERPLATE_TAIL[] = "}\n";

struct ParserState {
    std::string comment;
};

std::string &c_escape_string(std::string &comment) {
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    while (std::string::npos != (i = comment.find_first_of("\\\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\"", i))) {
        switch (comment[i]) {
            case '\\':  comment.replace(i, 0, "\\"); break;
            case '\a':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\a"); break;
            case '\b':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\b"); break;
            case '\f':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\f"); break;
            case '\n':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\n"); break;
            case '\r':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\r"); break;
            case '\t':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\t"); break;
            case '\v':  comment.replace(i, 1, "\\v"); break;
            default:    comment.replace(i, 0, "\\");
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    return comment.insert(0, "\"").append("\"");
}

std::ostream &emit_boilerplate_head(std::ostream &out, const std::string &filename) {
    out << BOILERPLATE_HEAD;
    if (!filename.empty()) {
        std::string fn(filename);
        out << c_escape_string(fn);
    }
    return out << std::endl;
}

std::ostream &emit_boilerplate_tail(std::ostream &out) {
    return out << BOILERPLATE_TAIL;
}

std::ostream &emit_comment(ParserState &state, std::ostream &out) {
    std::string leading_whitespace, trailing_whitespace;
    std::string::size_type pos;
    if (std::string::npos != (pos = state.comment.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v"))) {
        leading_whitespace = state.comment.substr(0, pos);
        state.comment = state.comment.substr(pos);
    }
    if (std::string::npos != (pos = state.comment.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v"))) {
        trailing_whitespace = state.comment.substr(pos + 1);
        state.comment.resize(pos + 1);
    }
    out << leading_whitespace;
    if (!state.comment.empty()) {
        out << "C(" << c_escape_string(state.comment) << ")";
        state.comment.clear();
    }
    out << trailing_whitespace;
    return out;
}

std::ostream &emit_instruction(ParserState &state, std::ostream &out, char instruction) {
    emit_comment(state, out);
    if ('W' == instruction) {
        out << "W{";    // Exception for readability
    } else if ('E' == instruction) {
        out << "E}";    // Exception for readability
    } else {
        out << instruction << ' ';
    }
    return out;
}

/* Try hard to preserve whitespace, especially line breaks, so that debuggers
   can deduce the right line numbers. */
std::ostream &emit_whitespace(ParserState &state, std::ostream &out, char c) {
    if (state.comment.empty()) {
        out << c;
    } else {
        state.comment += c;
    }
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
        emit_comment(state, out);
    }
    return out;
}

std::ostream &compile(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
    ParserState state;
    char c;
    while (in.get(c)) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            emit_whitespace(state, out, c);
        } else switch (c) {
            // Operations and their mnemonics
            case '<':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'L'); break;   // Left
            case '>':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'R'); break;   // Right
            case '-':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'M'); break;   // Minus
            case '+':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'P'); break;   // Plus
            case '[':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'W'); break;   // While
            case ']':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'E'); break;   // End
            case ',':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'I'); break;   // Input
            case '.':   emit_instruction(state, out, 'O'); break;   // Output
            default:    state.comment += c;
        }
    }
    emit_comment(state, out);
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::istream *in = &std::cin;
    std::ostream *out = &std::cout;

    std::ifstream infile;
    std::ofstream outfile;
    std::string filename;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (argv[i][0] && argv[i][0] != '-') {
            filename = argv[i];
            infile.open(filename);
            outfile.open(filename + ".c");
            in = &infile;
            out = &outfile;
            break;
        }
    }
    emit_boilerplate_head(*out, filename);
    compile(*in, *out);
    emit_boilerplate_tail(*out);
    *out << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but why are you methods all return a `std::ostream` reference? I guess it could facilitate method chaining but it's not really used as far as I can see.

Comment: @ChrisWue That was the intention, but it didn't turn out to be that useful in practice.

Comment: Would that not be a translator not a compiler.

Comment: @LokiAstari You could call it a translator.  However, it fits [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)'s definition of a _compiler_ as "A compiler is a computer program (or set of programs) that transforms source code written in a programming language (the source language) into another computer language (the target language, often having a binary form known as object code)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand

```
default:    comment.replace(i, 0, "\\");
```

makes

```
case '\\':  comment.replace(i, 0, "\\"); break;
```

useless.

Edit to add another comment :

Please activate all warnings on your code on one hand and on the generated code on the other hand. I think that :

```
void comment(int line, struct machine_state *m, const char *comment) {\n\
    return;\n\
    fprintf(stderr, \"%d %s\", line, comment);\n\
}\n\
```

shoud eventually warn you about unreachable code.