# Even more extensible and testable BuzzFizz

Tags: java, unit-testing, fizzbuzz, rags-to-riches

Inspired by [Extensible and testable FizzBuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74524/extensible-and-testable-fizzbuzz) I have decided to write my own implementation, partially based on my own answer and on the other answers.

First a warning to all of you: Never make such complicated code for such simple jobs!

Now the basic requirements of the code:

- Should be capable of solving the FizzBuzz problem.
- Should be capable of solving the FizzBuzz problem in a generic way, with any number of divisors and FizzBuzz-values.
- Should be able to count in a generic way, we see all original FizzBuzz statements where people only count over `int`. But that is not enough for us! With this solution we can count over any `Number` that is comparable. I'm aware of the performance hits of boxed int/long, but with Java Value Types and Generics over Value Types (including primitives) that should be a problem of the past in the future.

Then now the code will follow.

**FizzBuzz**

```
/**
 * Provides methods to convert numbers to their FizzBuzz-values given a set of rules.
 * 
 * <p>The FizzBuzz-value is a <tt>String</tt> obtained by applying a set of FizzBuzz-rules to a number.
 * An example of a FizzBuzz-rule is that a number that is divisible by a 3, must result in Fizz.
 * 
 * <p>If multiple FizzBuzz-values are obtained by applying multiple FizzBuzz-rules, then they will be joined together using an ordering and a delimiter, both the ordering and delimiter are configurable via the provided builder, respectively by providing a <tt>Comparator</tt> and providing a <tt>String</tt>.
 * An example of this is that in the classical FizzBuzz, the number 15 produces both <i>Fizz</i> and <i>Buzz</i>, with the default ordering and delimiter this will result in a FizzBuzz-value of <i>FizzBuzz</i>.
 * 
 * <p>This implementation only supports FizzBuzz-rules using divisibility.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <T>   The number used to count.
 */
public class FizzBuzz<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
    /** The sorted set of fizzers, to be used to calculate the FizzBuzz-value for every number. */
    private final SortedSet<FizzBuzzRule<T>> fizzBuzzRules;

    /** The increment operator, used to increment the number. */
    private final UnaryOperator<T> increment;

    /** The delimiter to be used when joining FizzBuzz values together. */
    private final String joinDelimiter;

    /**
     * Constructs a new FizzBuzz instance.
     * 
     * @param builder   The builder used to construct the new instance.
     */
    private FizzBuzz(final Builder<T> builder) {
        SortedSet<FizzBuzzRule<T>> tempFizzBuzzRules = new TreeSet<>(FizzBuzzRule.comparatorOnDivisor(builder.fizzBuzzRulesComparator));
        tempFizzBuzzRules.addAll(builder.fizzBuzzRules);
        this.fizzBuzzRules = Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet(tempFizzBuzzRules);
        this.increment = builder.increment;
        this.joinDelimiter = builder.joinDelimiter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the FizzBuzz-value of a number.
     * 
     * @param number    The non-null number for which the FizzBuzz-value should be determined.
     * @return  The FizzBuzz-value of the number.
     * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>number</tt> is null.
     */
    public String getValue(final T number) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(number, "number");
        String output = fizzBuzzRules.stream()
            .flatMap(fizzer -> fizzer.nameIfCanDivide(number).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(joinDelimiter));
        return (output.isEmpty() ? Objects.toString(number) : output);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a stream starting from a number.
     * 
     * <p>The user-supplied increment operator will be used to iterate from <tt>start</tt> onwards.
     * 
     * @param start The non-null number that is the inclusive starting point for the returned stream.
     * @return  A stream starting from the number.
     * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>start</tt> is null.
     */
    public Stream<String> rangeFrom(final T start) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(start, "start");
        return Stream.iterate(start, increment).map(this::getValue);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a builder that can be used to build FizzBuzz instances.
     * 
     * @param <T>   The number used to count.
     * @param increment The increment operator.
     * @param isDivisble    The predicate to check whether the <i>first</i> number is divisible by the <i>second</i> number.
     * @return  The builder instance.
     */
    public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> Builder<T> builder(final UnaryOperator<T> increment, final BiPredicate<T, T> isDivisble) {
        return new Builder<>(increment, isDivisble);
    }

    /**
     * Encapsulates a FizzBuzz-rule.
     * 
     * <p>It stores the FizzBuzz-value, divisor and "is divisible by predicate"-for a FizzBuzz-rule, and provides methods to work with them.
     * 
     * @param <T>   The number that is used by the FizzBuzz-rule.
     */
    private static class FizzBuzzRule<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
        /** The FizzBuzz-value of this FizzBuzz-rule. */
        private final String name;

        /** The divisor for this FizzBuzz-rule. */
        private final T divisor;

        /** The "is divisible by"-predicate for this FizzBuzz-rule. */
        private final BiPredicate<T, T> isDivisibleBy;

        /**
         * Constructs a new Fizzer instance.
         * 
         * @param name  The FizzBuzz-value of the FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @param divisor   The divisor number for this FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @param isDivisibleBy   The "is divisible by"-predicate for this FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>name</tt>, <tt>divisor</tt> or <tt>isDivisibleBy</tt> is null.
         */
        private FizzBuzzRule(final String name, final T divisor, final BiPredicate<T, T> isDivisibleBy) {
            this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name");
            this.divisor = Objects.requireNonNull(divisor, "divisor");
            this.isDivisibleBy = Objects.requireNonNull(isDivisibleBy, "isDivisibleBy");
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether this FizzBuzz-rule can divide the given number.
         * 
         * <p>Returns true if and only if the given number is divisible by the divisor of this FizzBuzz-rule.
         * 
         * @param number    The non-null number to test divisibility for.
         * @return  Whether this FizzBuzz-rule can divide the given number.
         * @throws  NullPointerException    If <tt>number</tt> is null.
         */
        private boolean canDivide(final T number) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(number, "number");
            return isDivisibleBy.test(number, divisor);
        }

        /**
         * Returns an Optional, containing the FizzBuzz-value of this FizzBuzz-rule if and only if the given number is divisible by the divisor of this FizzBuzz-rule.
         * 
         * @param number    The non-null number to test divisiblity for.
         * @return  An <tt>Optional</tt>, containing the FizzBuzz-value of this FizzBuzz-rule if and only if the given number is divisible by the divisor of this FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>number</tt> is null.
         */
        private Optional<String> nameIfCanDivide(final T number) {
            return (canDivide(number) ? Optional.of(name) : Optional.empty());
        }

        /**
         * Returns a Comparator on the divisor of this FizzBuzz-rule using a supplied Comparator that can be used on numbers.
         * 
         * @param <T>   The number that is used by this comparator.
         * @param comparator    The non-null comparator that can be used to compare numbers.
         * @return  A <tt>Comparator</tt> on the divisor of this FizzBuzz-rule using <tt>comparator</tt> that can be used on numbers.
         * @throws  NullPointerException    If <tt>comparator</tt> is null.
         */
        private static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> Comparator<FizzBuzzRule<T>> comparatorOnDivisor(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(comparator, "comparator");
            return Comparator.comparing(fizzer -> fizzer.divisor, comparator);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A builder class that can be used to build FizzBuzz instances.
     * 
     * <p>The minimum requirement to build a FizzBuzz instance is to provide an increment operator and an "is divisible by"-predicate.
     * It is recommended that you add a number of name-divisor pairs that can then be added to the list of FizzBuzz-rules.
     * Optionally you can provide a custom comparator for the ordering of the FizzBuzz-rules and a custom join delimiter that is used when joining multiple FizzBuzz-values together.
     * 
     * <p>In a normal setup in the classical FizzBuzz example, the number 15 will be converted to <i>FizzBuzz</i>.
     * If you provide a reversed comparator and a join delimiter consisting of a single blank, then it will be converted to <i>Buzz Fizz</i>.
     * 
     * @param <T>   The number that will be used for counting.
     */
    public static class Builder<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
        /** The increment operator to be used by the FizzBuzz instances that will be built. */
        private final UnaryOperator<T> increment;

        /** The "is divisible by"-predicate to be used by the resulting FizzBuzz-rules. */
        private final BiPredicate<T, T> isDivisibleBy;

        /** The unordered set of FizzBuzz-rules. */
        private final Set<FizzBuzzRule<T>> fizzBuzzRules = new HashSet<>();

        /** The comparator to be used to order the set of FizzBuzz-rules. */
        private Comparator<T> fizzBuzzRulesComparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();

        /** The join delimiter to be used to join multiple FizzBuzz-values together. */
        private String joinDelimiter = "";

        /**
         * Constructs a new Builder instance that can be used to build FizzBuzz instances.
         * 
         * @param increment The non-null increment operator.
         * @param isDivisibleBy   The non-null "is divisible by"-predicate.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>increment</tt> or <tt>isDivibleBy</tt> is null.
         */
        public Builder(final UnaryOperator<T> increment, final BiPredicate<T, T> isDivisibleBy) {
            this.increment = Objects.requireNonNull(increment, "increment");
            this.isDivisibleBy = Objects.requireNonNull(isDivisibleBy, "isDivisibleBy");
        }

        /**
         * Sets the comparator used by this builder.
         * 
         * @param comparator    The comparator used by this builder.
         * @return  This builder instance.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>comparator</tt> is null.
         */
        public Builder<T> comparator(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
            this.fizzBuzzRulesComparator = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator, "comparator");
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the join delimiter used by this builder.
         * 
         * @param joinDelimiter The join delimiter used by this builder.
         * @return  This builder instance.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>joinDelimiter</tt> is null.
         */
        public Builder<T> joinDelimiter(final String joinDelimiter) {
            this.joinDelimiter = Objects.requireNonNull(joinDelimiter, "joinDelimiter");
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Adds a name-divisor pair to this builder.
         * 
         * <p>The name-divisor pair will be converted to a FizzBuzz-rule and added to the list of FizzBuzz-rules in this builder.
         * 
         * @param name  The FizzBuzz-value of a FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @param divisor   The divisor of a FizzBuzz-rule.
         * @return  This builder instance.
         * @throws IllegalStateException    If the supplied divisor is already in use in a different FizzBuzz-rule in this builder.
         * @throws NullPointerException If <tt>name</tt> or <tt>divisor</tt> is null.
         */
        public Builder<T> add(final String name, final T divisor) {
            if (fizzBuzzRules.stream().anyMatch(fizzBuzzRule -> fizzBuzzRule.divisor.equals(divisor))) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("The divisor " + divisor + " is already mapped");
            }
            fizzBuzzRules.add(new FizzBuzzRule<>(name, divisor, isDivisibleBy));
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Builds a new FizzBuzz instance.
         * 
         * @return  A FizzBuzz instance produced by this builder.
         */
        public FizzBuzz<T> build() {
            return new FizzBuzz<>(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**FizzBuzzDemo**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class FizzBuzzDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FizzBuzz<Integer> fizzBuzzInteger = FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, 
            (number, divisor) -> number % divisor == 0)
            .add("Fizz", 3)
            .add("Buzz", 5)
            .build();
        fizzBuzzInteger.rangeFrom(1).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();

        FizzBuzz<BigInteger> fizzBuzzBigInteger = FizzBuzz.<BigInteger>builder(bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE), 
            (number, divisor) -> number.mod(divisor).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0)
            .comparator(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .joinDelimiter(" ")
            .add("Fizz", BigInteger.valueOf(3))
            .add("Buzz", BigInteger.valueOf(5))
            .build();
        fizzBuzzBigInteger.rangeFrom(BigInteger.ONE).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**FizzBuzzBuilderTest**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class FizzBuzzBuilderTest {
    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testConstructorNullIncrement() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(null, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testConstructorNullIsDivisibleBy() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testComparator() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        assertEquals(builder, builder.comparator(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testComparatorNullComparator() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.comparator(null);
    }


    @Test
    public void testJoinDelimiter() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.joinDelimiter("");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testJoinDelimiterNullJoinDelimiter() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        assertEquals(builder, builder.joinDelimiter(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        assertEquals(builder, builder.add("Fizz", 3).add("Buzz", 5));
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testAddAlreadyMapped() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.add("Fizz", 3);
        builder.add("Buzz", 3);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testAddNullName() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.add(null, 3);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testAddNullDivisor() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.add("Fizz", null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildWithoutAnything() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        assertNotNull(builder.build());
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildWithEverything() {
        FizzBuzz.Builder<Integer> builder = new FizzBuzz.Builder<>(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0);
        builder.add("Fizz", 3);
        builder.add("Buzz", 5);
        builder.comparator(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        builder.joinDelimiter(" ");
        assertNotNull(builder.build());
    }
}
```

**FizzBuzzTest**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class FizzBuzzTest {
    private final FizzBuzz<Integer> fizzBuzz = FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, (number, divisor) -> number % divisor == 0)
                    .add("Fizz", 3)
                    .add("Buzz", 5)
                    .build();

    @Test
    public void testBuilder() {
        assertNotNull(FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, (i, j) -> i % j == 0));
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testGetValueNullNumber() {
        fizzBuzz.getValue(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRangeFromNullStart() {
        fizzBuzz.rangeFrom(null);
    }

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class Parametrized<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            Map<Integer, String> fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap = new HashMap<>();
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(1, "1");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(2, "2");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(3, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(4, "4");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(5, "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(6, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(7, "7");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(8, "8");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(9, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(10, "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(11, "11");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(12, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(13, "13");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(14, "14");
            fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap.put(15, "FizzBuzz");

            Map<BigInteger, String> fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap = new HashMap<>();
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(1), "1");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(2), "2");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(3), "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(4), "4");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(5), "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(6), "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(7), "7");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(8), "8");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(9), "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(10), "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(11), "11");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(12), "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(13), "13");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(14), "14");
            fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(15), "FizzBuzz");

            Map<Integer, String> fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap = new HashMap<>();
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(1, "1");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(2, "Woof");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(3, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(4, "Woof");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(5, "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(6, "WoofFizz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(7, "7");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(8, "Woof");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(9, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(10, "WoofBuzz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(11, "11");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(12, "WoofFizz");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(13, "13");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(14, "Woof");
            fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap.put(15, "FizzBuzz");

            Map<Integer, String> fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap = new HashMap<>();
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(1, "1");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(2, "2");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(3, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(4, "4");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(5, "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(6, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(7, "7");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(8, "8");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(9, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(10, "Buzz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(11, "11");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(12, "Fizz");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(13, "13");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(14, "14");
            fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap.put(15, "Buzz Fizz");

            return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[] {
                    //regular FizzBuzz on Integer with {3, 5}
                    FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, (number, divisor) -> number % divisor == 0)
                        .add("Fizz", 3)
                        .add("Buzz", 5)
                        .build(),
                    fizzBuzzIntegerResultMap,
                    1,
                    (Object)(UnaryOperator<Integer>)i -> i + 1
                },
                new Object[] {
                    //regular FizzBuzz on BigInteger with {3, 5}
                    FizzBuzz.<BigInteger>builder(bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE), (number, divisor) -> number.mod(divisor).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0)
                        .add("Fizz", BigInteger.valueOf(3))
                        .add("Buzz", BigInteger.valueOf(5))
                        .build(),
                    fizzBuzzBigIntegerResultMap,
                    BigInteger.valueOf(1),
                    (Object)(UnaryOperator<BigInteger>)bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE)
                },
                new Object[] {
                    //FizzBuzz on Integer with {5, 3, 2}
                    FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, (number, divisor) -> number % divisor == 0)
                        .add("Buzz", 5)
                        .add("Fizz", 3)
                        .add("Woof", 2)
                        .build(),
                    fizzBuzzWoofIntegerReversedDivisorsResultMap,
                    1,
                    (Object)(UnaryOperator<Integer>)i -> i + 1
                },
                new Object[] {
                    //regular FizzBuzz on Integer with {3, 5} with reversed comparator and blank string join
                    FizzBuzz.<Integer>builder(i -> i + 1, (number, divisor) -> number % divisor == 0)
                        .add("Fizz", 3)
                        .add("Buzz", 5)
                        .comparator(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                        .joinDelimiter(" ")
                        .build(),
                    fizzBuzzIntegerWithReversedComparatorAndBlankStringJoinResultMap,
                    1,
                    (Object)(UnaryOperator<Integer>)i -> i + 1
                }
            );
        }

        @Parameter(0)
        public FizzBuzz<T> fizzBuzz;

        @Parameter(1)
        public Map<T, String> resultMap;

        @Parameter(2)
        public T start;

        @Parameter(3)
        public UnaryOperator<T> increment;

        @Test
        public void testGetValue() {
            resultMap.forEach((number, fizzBuzzValue) -> assertEquals(fizzBuzzValue, fizzBuzz.getValue(number)));
        }

        @Test
        public void testRangeFrom() {
            String[] fizzBuzzValues = fizzBuzz.rangeFrom(start).limit(15).toArray(String[]::new);

            T element = start;
            for (String fizzBuzzValue : fizzBuzzValues) {
                assertEquals(resultMap.get(element), fizzBuzzValue);
                element = increment.apply(element);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I would like a review on every aspect of my code.

Comment: Can the downvoter please indicate what is wrong with this question? Other than that it involves FizzBuzz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hm, how do I put this nicely: you have overengineered an exercise that's designed to serve as a basic sanity check to weed out talentless job candidates pretending as programmers. Aaaaaaaah! ;-)  *// kidding!*

I understand your pain about fizz-buzz implementations that only work with `int` values; however, generics is not a great way to do this. The problem definition only makes sense with integers, which limits the possible Java types to:

- `int` / Integer
- `long` / Long
- `BigInteger`

Since these types are too similar, 
this is not a typical pattern for using generics,
in fact using generics for this is really awkward.

A better solution would be to use `BigInteger` internally,
and provide overloaded methods for `int` and `long`,
which will all convert their parameters to the largest supported type (`BigInteger`).

This will have the following advantages:

- The fizz-buzz logic can remain encapsulated: no need to force users to pass in the divisible predicate. The duplicated logic in all unit tests and every time you use the class will go away.
- The fizz-buzz logic can remain encapsulated: a fizzbuzzer is of not much use if you have to tell it how to fizzbuzz!
- The code will become a lot simpler

Another thing, the `rangeFrom` doesn't belong to `FizzBuzz` class,
as it adds an additional responsibility.
It's a bit like feature creep.
It seems convenient to provide this method,
but it weakens the API.
It would be better to move this logic to another class,
for example `FizzBuzzStream.fromRange(start, end)`,
and stick to the single responsibility principle.