# BF Interpreter, Follow-up: ++;++; is now +=2;

Tags: java, interpreter, brainfuck

Follow-up to: [Brainfuck Interpreter: Slower than a Snail?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108630/brainfuck-interpreter-slower-than-a-snail)

Many improvements have been added, including:

- Remembering where the matching `[` and `]` is
- Combining `+`s, `-`s, `<`s, and `>`s into groups
- Providing the option to not optimize the code

I have no idea how to use JUnit to test on the output, so I stuck with `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BFCode code = new BFCode(
                "++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>>++++++++++>->>>>>>>>>>-->+++++++[->++++++++++<]>[->+>+>+>+<<<<]+++>>+++>>>++++++++[-<++++<++++<++++>>>]+++++[-<++++<++++>>]>-->++++++[->+++++++++++<]>[->+>+>+>+<<<<]+++++>>+>++++++>++++++>++++++++[-<++++<++++<++++>>>]++++++[-<+++<+++<+++>>>]>-->---+[-<+]-<<[->>>+>++[-->++]-->+++[---<-->+>-[<<++[>]]>++[--+[-<+]->>[-]+++++[---->++++]-->[->+<]>>[.>]>++]-->+++]---+[-<+]->>-[+>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->->+<<]>[-]>[<++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]]<<<.<]");
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        BFInterpreter.interpret(code);
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - time) + '\n');
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        time = System.nanoTime();
        BFInterpreter.interpretNoOptimizations(code);
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);
    }

}
```

The `Thread.sleep(1000)` is there for me to see a quick result before moving on to the next test.

Output:

```
1
2
Fizz
...
98
Fizz
Buzz
39662432

1
2
...
98
Fizz
Buzz
26999614
```

As the code for Fizzbuzz is already optimized, it is unnecessary to optimize it again. If it were to include a bunch of extra `+-` and `<>` groups though, the results would be different.

As you can see, though, even the optimize-and-run method ran about twice as fast as the previous post.

**BFInterpreter.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BFInterpreter {

    public static final int BF_MEMORY_SIZE = 30000;

    private static final InputStreamReader INPUT = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    private static final int BYTE_SIZE = 256;
    private static final int HALF_BYTE = BYTE_SIZE / 2;

    public static void interpretNoOptimizations(BFCode code) {
        // Check for errors
        if (hasErrors(code.getCode())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("code has at least one error in it");
        }
        char[] commands = code.getCode().toCharArray();
        interpret(commands);
    }

    public static void interpret(BFCode code) {
        // Check for errors
        if (hasErrors(code.getCode())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("code has at least one error in it");
        }
        char[] commands = code.getOptimizedCode().getCode().toCharArray();
        interpret(commands);
    }

    private static void interpret(char[] commands) {
        // -128 = 0, 0 = 128, 127 = 255 etc.
        byte[] bfMemory = new byte[BF_MEMORY_SIZE];
        Arrays.fill(bfMemory, Byte.MIN_VALUE);
        Map<Integer, Integer> endKeyLoopMatch = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> beginKeyLoopMatch = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0, pointer = 0, len = commands.length; i < len; i++) {
            int times;
            switch (commands[i]) {
            case '+':
                times = 1;
                while (commands[++i] == '+') {
                    times++;
                }
                i--;
                bfMemory[pointer] += times;
                break;
            case '-':
                times = 1;
                while (commands[++i] == '-') {
                    times++;
                }
                i--;
                bfMemory[pointer] -= times;
                break;
            case '<':
                times = 1;
                while (commands[++i] == '<') {
                    times++;
                }
                i--;
                pointer -= times;
                if (pointer < 0) {
                    pointer += BF_MEMORY_SIZE * (pointer % BF_MEMORY_SIZE + 1);
                }
                break;
            case '>':
                times = 1;
                while (commands[++i] == '>') {
                    times++;
                }
                i--;
                pointer += times;
                if (pointer >= BF_MEMORY_SIZE) {
                    pointer -= BF_MEMORY_SIZE * (pointer % BF_MEMORY_SIZE);
                }
                break;
            case '.':
                System.out.print((char) (bfMemory[pointer] + HALF_BYTE));
                break;
            case ',':
                try {
                    bfMemory[pointer] = (byte) (INPUT.read() - HALF_BYTE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // EOF? no change
                }
                break;
            case '[':
                if (bfMemory[pointer] == Byte.MIN_VALUE) { // == 0
                    Integer index = endKeyLoopMatch.get(i);
                    if (index == null) {
                        index = indexOfMatchingCloseBracket(commands, i);
                        beginKeyLoopMatch.put(index, i);
                        endKeyLoopMatch.put(i, index);
                    }
                    i = index;
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if (bfMemory[pointer] != Byte.MIN_VALUE) { // != 0
                    Integer index = beginKeyLoopMatch.get(i);
                    if (index == null) {
                        index = indexOfMatchingOpenBracket(commands, i);
                        beginKeyLoopMatch.put(i, index);
                        endKeyLoopMatch.put(index, i);
                    }
                    i = index;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasErrors(String bfCode) {
        // each [ must have a ]
        char[] commands = bfCode.toCharArray();
        int diff = 0;
        for (char command : commands) {
            if (command == '[') {
                diff++;
            } else if (command == ']') {
                diff--;
            }
            if (diff < 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return diff != 0;
    }

    private static int indexOfMatchingCloseBracket(char[] commands, int currentIndex) {
        int index = currentIndex;
        int numOfOpeningBrackets = 1;
        while (numOfOpeningBrackets != 0) {
            switch (commands[++index]) {
            case '[':
                numOfOpeningBrackets++;
                break;
            case ']':
                numOfOpeningBrackets--;
                break;
            default:

            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static int indexOfMatchingOpenBracket(char[] commands, int currentIndex) {
        int index = currentIndex;
        int numOfClosingBrackets = 1;
        while (numOfClosingBrackets != 0) {
            switch (commands[--index]) {
            case '[':
                numOfClosingBrackets--;
                break;
            case ']':
                numOfClosingBrackets++;
                break;
            default:

            }
        }
        return index;
    }

}
```

**BFCode.java**

This has not changed, but here it is anyway:

```
public class BFCode {

    private final String code;

    public BFCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public BFCode getOptimizedCode() {
        return new BFCode(BFOptimizer.optimize(code));
    }

}
```

**BFOptimizer.java**

Again, not changed:

```
public class BFOptimizer {

    public static final String NOT_BF_REGEX = "[^\\Q><+-.,[]\\E]";
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    public static String optimize(String bfCode) {
        bfCode = bfCode.replaceAll(NOT_BF_REGEX, EMPTY_STRING);
        while (true) {
            String result = bfCode.replaceAll("(\\+\\-)|(\\-\\+)|(<>)|(><)", EMPTY_STRING);
            if (result.equals(bfCode)) {
                return result;
            }
            bfCode = result;
        }
    }

}
```

Concerns:

1. Looking at the first improvement:

   > Remembering where the matching `[` and `]` is

   I noticed something. Without that implemented:

   ```
   ...
   37740054
   ...
   24490473
   ```

   It seems to be slightly faster. Is the first improvement worth it? Can it be improved?
2. Is it still slow?
3. And as usual, anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Object-oriented design

As [before](/a/111868/9357), you are not using interfaces effectively.  When two pieces of code serve the same role, then they should implement the same interface.  Instead of

> ```
> public class BFInterpreter {
>     public static void interpretNoOptimizations(BFCode code) { … }
>     public static void interpret(BFCode code) { … }
> }
> ```

you should have

```
public interface BFInterpreter {  // or class, or abstract class
    void interpret(BFCode code);
}

public class NaiveBFInterpreter implements BFInterpreter {
    @Override
    public void interpret(BFCode code) { … }
}

public class OptimizingBFInterpreter implements BFInterpreter {
    @Override
    public void interpret(BFCode code) { … }
}
```

I don't think that `BFCode.getOptimizedCode()` is necessary.  Just call `BFOptimizer.optimize(…)` directly instead.  Then, the `BFCode` class is nothing more than a glorified `String`, so you might as well eliminate it in favour of using `String` directly.  (But read on…)

### Optimization

Eliminating comments would likely help in some cases.  Defining the constant `public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";` is just silly, though.

Eliminating pairs of mutually cancelling operations is a pretty weak optimization.  It would only have an effect on code that was deliberately pessimized in the first place, which would be unlikely.

What *would* actually make a difference to performance is JITting the code: building jump tables and coalescing consecutive `+`/`-`/`<`/`>` operations so that you don't have to execute `while` loops like this within `interpret()`:

> ```
> case '+':
>     times = 1;
>     while (commands[++i] == '+') {
>         times++;
>     }
>     i--;
>     bfMemory[pointer] += times;
>     break;
> ```

To do that, you'll need `BFCode` to use a richer representation than just a `String`.