# Brainfuck interpreter in F# (by a C# developer)

Tags: f#, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm a C# developer learning F#. I have a lot of questions about practices and principles within the code. I would like to know what a "native" F# developer would've done differently.

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module MyApp

module Railway = 

   // NOTE: will Tee make sense to most people?  it's from this https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/      
   let Tee func value = 
      func value
      value

module Stack =

   // NOTE: I've just made functions to give me stack-like behavior.  should i make
   //       a whole type for this?  what might it look like?
   // NOTE: Upper or lower case function names?  the built-in collections
   //       all have lower, but i read that shouldn't be practiced anymore.
   //       can't remember where.  any thoughts?
   let Push stack value = 
      value :: stack

   let Pop stack = 
      match stack with
      | []  -> None,  stack
      | [v] -> Some(v), []
      | _   -> Some(List.head stack), List.tail stack

[<AutoOpen>]
module State =

   open System.Text

   type State = { 
      Index : int
      Pointer : int   
      Stack : int list
      Input : byte list
      Memory : byte array
      }

   // NOTE: no one is forced to use this constructor function.  what if they
   //       initialize their own "state" improperly?
   let Create (input : string) = 
      {  Index = 0
         Pointer = 0
         Stack= List.empty
         Input = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input) |> Array.toList 
         Memory = Array.init 100  (fun i -> 0uy) }

[<AutoOpen>]
module Source =

   type Instruction = 
      | INCPTR
      | DECPTR
      | INCVAL
      | DECVAL
      | OUTVAL
      | INPVAL
      | WHILE
      | WEND
      | NOOP

   // NOTE: is this translation worth it?  i'm an enterprise developer at heart.
   //       defining all the things always feels good, but it does add more code
   //       to the mix.
   let Compile (code : string) : Instruction list =
      seq {
         for c in code do
            match c with
            | '>' -> yield INCPTR
            | '<' -> yield DECPTR
            | '+' -> yield INCVAL
            | '-' -> yield DECVAL
            | '.' -> yield OUTVAL
            | ',' -> yield INPVAL
            | '[' -> yield WHILE
            | ']' -> yield WEND         
            | _   -> yield NOOP
            }
      |> Seq.toList

module Brainfart =

   open System.Text
   open System

   // NOTE: have a function for these one-liners for consistency?  or inline it?
   let IncPtr (state : State) : State =
      {state with Pointer = state.Pointer + 1}

   let DecPtr (state : State) : State =
      {state with Pointer = state.Pointer - 1}

   let IncVal (state : State) : Unit =
      // NOTE: I'm mutating the state of the incoming variable, then this has the appropriate optimization effect, 
      //       but my state is only mostly immutable. is there some other way to structure this that is more 
      //       natural in F#?
      state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <- (state.Memory.[state.Pointer] + 1uy)

   let DecVal (state : State) : Unit =
      state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <- (state.Memory.[state.Pointer] - 1uy)

   let OutVal (state : State) : Unit =      
      state.Memory.[state.Pointer] 
      |> Array.singleton 
      |> ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString
      |> printf "%s" 
      |> ignore

   let InpVal (state : State) : State = 
      // NOTE: this is a two step operation.  any way to make this nicer?
      let o, i = Stack.Pop state.Input
      match o with
      | Some v -> state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <- v
      | None   -> state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <- 0uy   
      {state with Input = i}      

   let While (state : State) : State = 
      {state with Stack = state.Index :: state.Stack}

   let Wend (state : State) : State = 
      if state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <> 0uy then 
         {state with Index = List.head state.Stack} 
      else 
         // NOTE: this is a two step operation.  any way to make this nicer?
         let o, s = Stack.Pop state.Stack
         match o with
         // NOTE: i don't use this variable.  any way to not declare it?
         | Some v -> {state with Stack = s} 
         | None -> state

   let IncIndex (state : State) : State =
      {state with Index = state.Index + 1}

   let RunInstruction (instruction : Instruction) (state : State) : State =
      match instruction with
      | INCPTR -> IncPtr state
      | DECPTR -> DecPtr state      
      | INCVAL -> Railway.Tee IncVal state
      | DECVAL -> Railway.Tee DecVal state      
      | OUTVAL -> Railway.Tee OutVal state      
      | INPVAL -> InpVal state      
      | WHILE  -> While state
      | WEND   -> Wend state
      | NOOP   -> state
      // NOTE: most of the operations above make a new copy of the state and IncIndex
      //       doubles-down on that.  i had the increments inline for each operation
      //       but felt like it was too much copied code.  any thoughts?  it is nicer
      //       to look at this way.
      |> IncIndex 

   let rec RunInstructions (code : Instruction list) (state : State) : State =
      if state.Index = code.Length then
         state
      else
        state |> RunInstruction code.[state.Index] |> RunInstructions code

   // NOTE: i get very self-conscious about explicitly type signatures, but they
   //       are very useful to me.  they help with intellisense and at-a-glance
   //       "what does this method do" stuff.  should i work on getting away from
   //       doing this?
   let Run (input : string) (code : Instruction list) : State =
      let f = printfn "" 
      State.Create input 
      |> RunInstructions code      
      // NOTE: any nicer way to do this?  
      |> Railway.Tee (fun s -> printfn "")
```

Here's the fsx script I use for the "Hello World" program.

```
Source.Compile "++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>++++<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>>++++.<++.<++++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.>+." 

|> Brainfart.Run ""
```

**EDIT**

I recognize have a do/while in my code vs a while/do and that i need to change it.  I also have a bunch of other questions in the code that are of interest to me.  I'd appreciate any insight anyone can give.

Comment: For future reference: Test your interpretation implementation on [FizzBuzz in Brainfuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57382/31562) if that doesn't print FizzBuzz, you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> let While (state : State) : State = 
>    {state with Stack = state.Index :: state.Stack}
>
> let Wend (state : State) : State = 
>    if state.Memory.[state.Pointer] <> 0uy then 
>       {state with Index = List.head state.Stack} 
>    else 
>       // NOTE: this is a two step operation.  any way to make this nicer?
>       let o, s = Stack.Pop state.Stack
>       match o with
>       // NOTE: i don't use this variable.  any way to not declare it?
>       | Some v -> {state with Stack = s} 
>       | None -> state
> ```

The `While` handler has no conditional logic, which is weird… and wrong.  Instead, the conditional logic is in `Wend`.  You have essentially committed the same mistake as in [this implementation](/a/144923/9357).

So, `Brainfart` is indeed an appropriate name for your module.  =)

Comment: is this a semantics argument or something deeper?  would calling them "Do" and "Until" square it away?  will the system behave differently if i make the changes you suggest?

Comment: nm.  you are correct sir.  thanks for the input.