# Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, recursion, interpreter, brainfuck

Okay, so I just started learning Haskell around a week ago and this is my first real program that I worked on all of yesterday with a lot of help from IRC. I know that using indicies and arrays is not very "Haskellish" but I found constantly manipulating lists and traversing them was extremely slow and sometimes the program took over 10 minutes to execute while this version is instant.

Afterwards I found you can do it with some Zipper package in 10 lines of code trivially but I didn't want to use anything too fancy.

I find that when I'm writing Haskell because there is no state I find myself simulating state with function parameters (saving variables and mutating them in a recursive call). I'm pretty sure I took it too far because most of these functions take four parameters and rarely change them but I'm not sure about many alternatives.

I haven't gotten to monads, functors, or applicatives yet, so while I'm sure they could solve this quite elegantly, they're still just magic to me. Unless the explanation is quite simple, I'd prefer if replies didn't mention them. I'm mostly looking for refactorings, style-advice, and better ways of implementing some things.

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Array

-- Current Index, Indentation Depth, Program Array -> Bracket Index
prevBracketIndex :: Int -> Int -> Array Int Char -> Int
prevBracketIndex i depth cs
    | cs ! i == '[' = if (depth - 1) == 0 then i else prevBracketIndex (i - 1) (depth - 1) cs
    | cs ! i == ']' = prevBracketIndex (i - 1) (depth + 1) cs
    | otherwise = prevBracketIndex (i - 1) depth cs

nextBracketIndex :: Int -> Int -> Array Int Char -> Int
nextBracketIndex i depth cs
    | cs ! i == '[' = nextBracketIndex (i + 1) (depth + 1) cs
    | cs ! i == ']' = if (depth - 1) == 0 then i else nextBracketIndex (i + 1) (depth - 1) cs
    | otherwise = nextBracketIndex (i + 1) depth cs

execCode :: Int -> S.Seq Int -> Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode tapePos ts codePos cs
    | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
    | cmd == '+' = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value + 1) ts) nextPos cs
    | cmd == '-' = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value - 1) ts) nextPos cs
    | cmd == '>' = execCode (tapePos + 1) ts nextPos cs
    | cmd == '<' = execCode (tapePos - 1) ts nextPos cs
    | cmd == '[' && value == 0 = execCode tapePos ts (nextBracketIndex codePos 0 cs + 1) cs
    | cmd == ']' && value /= 0 = execCode tapePos ts (prevBracketIndex codePos 0 cs + 1) cs
    | cmd == '.' = putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execCode tapePos ts nextPos cs
    | cmd == ',' = do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos cs }
    | otherwise = execCode tapePos ts nextPos cs
    where value = S.index ts tapePos
          cmd = cs ! codePos
          nextPos = codePos + 1

tape = S.fromList $ replicate 30000 0

main = do
    file <- readFile "example.bf"
    execCode 0 tape 0 (listArray (0, length file - 1) file)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `case` instead of `==` and guards everywhere:

```
prevBracketIndex :: Int -> Int -> Array Int Char -> Int
prevBracketIndex i depth cs = case cs ! i of
    '[' -> if (depth - 1) == 0 then i else prevBracketIndex (i - 1) (depth - 1) cs
    ']' -> prevBracketIndex (i - 1) (depth + 1) cs
    _ -> prevBracketIndex (i - 1) depth cs
```

Use `State` and `lens` to carry state around instead of manual threading.

Use `monad-loops` to spin the loop instead of manual tail calls.

`prevBracketIndex` should avoid recursion too by using lists of indices.

Initial `depth` is always 0 in `prevBracketIndex` so it should be made local to improve readability. Also, cs is not changed across recursive calls so there is no need to pass it across. Applying both ideas:

```
prevBracketIndex :: Int -> Array Int Char -> Int
prevBracketIndex i cs = pbi i 0 where
    pbi i depth = case cs ! i of
        '[' -> if (depth - 1) == 0 then i else pbi (i - 1) (depth - 1)
        ']' -> pbi (i - 1) (depth + 1)
        _ -> pbi (i - 1) depth
```

For `execCode` we can do the same transformation: `cs` is invariant across loops, and initial positions are always 0.

Note also that `prevBracketIndex` can be completely precalculated (replaced by a single array lookup), as `cs` doesn't change.

Applying everything above but `case` we get:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Array
import Data.List


cachePrev cs = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumL f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) = case c of
        '[' -> (i : l, Nothing)
        ']' -> (tail l, Just $ head l)
        _ -> (l, Nothing)

cacheNext cs = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumR f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) = case c of
        ']' -> (i : l, Nothing)
        '[' -> (tail l, Just $ head l)
        _ -> (l, Just i)

cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error "oops!"
    Just idx -> idx

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = execCode 0 ts 0 where
    prev = cachePrev cs
    next = cacheNext cs

    execCode tapePos ts codePos
        | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
        | cmd == '+' = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value + 1) ts) nextPos
        | cmd == '-' = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value - 1) ts) nextPos
        | cmd == '>' = execCode (tapePos + 1) ts nextPos
        | cmd == '<' = execCode (tapePos - 1) ts nextPos
        | cmd == '[' && value == 0 = execCode tapePos ts (cache next codePos + 1)
        | cmd == ']' && value /= 0 = execCode tapePos ts (cache prev codePos + 1)
        | cmd == '.' = putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execCode tapePos ts nextPos
        | cmd == ',' = do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos }
        | otherwise = execCode tapePos ts nextPos
        where
            value = S.index ts tapePos
            cmd = cs ! codePos
            nextPos = codePos + 1
```

For tests I found `csFromString` to be a convenient helper:

```
csFromString file = listArray (0, length file - 1) file
```

And it helps to write `main` in a more compact way:

```
main = readFile "example.bf" >>= execCode' tape . csFromString
```

Now let's apply the `case` proposal:

```
execCode _ _ codePos | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
execCode tapePos ts codePos = case cs ! codePos of
    '+' -> execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value + 1) ts) nextPos
    '-' -> execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (value - 1) ts) nextPos
    '>' -> execCode (tapePos + 1) ts nextPos
    '<' -> execCode (tapePos - 1) ts nextPos
    '[' -> if value == 0 then execCode tapePos ts (cache next codePos + 1) else execNext 
    ']' -> if value /= 0 then execCode tapePos ts (cache prev codePos + 1) else execNext
    '.' -> putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execNext
    ',' -> do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos }
    _ -> execNext
    where
        value = S.index ts tapePos
        nextPos = codePos + 1
        execNext = execCode tapePos ts nextPos
```

Now `cmd` is not needed anymore, and `[` and `]` required some additional plumbing.

Now let's remove duplication in 3 symmetrical pairs of instructions - `updatePos`, `updateVal` and `branch`:

```
execCode _ _ codePos | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
execCode tapePos ts codePos = case cs ! codePos of
    '+' -> updatePos succ
    '-' -> updatePos pred
    '>' -> updateVal succ
    '<' -> updateVal pred
    '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
    ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
    '.' -> putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execNext
    ',' -> do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos }
    _ -> execNext
    where
        value = S.index ts tapePos
        nextPos = codePos + 1
        execNext = execCode tapePos ts nextPos

        updatePos f = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos
        updateVal f = execCode (f tapePos) ts nextPos
        branch cond dir = if cond value then execCode tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1) else execNext
```

Now it's time to remove duplication between `cachePrev` and `cacheNext`:

```
mkCache cs mapAccumX bracketPush bracketPop = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumX f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) 
        | c == bracketPush = (i : l, Nothing)
        | c == bracketPop = (tail l, Just $ head l)
        | otherwise = (l, Nothing)

cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error "oops!"
    Just idx -> idx

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = execCode 0 ts 0 where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode _ _ codePos | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
    execCode tapePos ts codePos = case cs ! codePos of
        '+' -> updatePos succ
        '-' -> updatePos pred
        '>' -> updateVal succ
        '<' -> updateVal pred
        '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
        ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
        '.' -> putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execNext
        ',' -> do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos }
        _ -> execNext
        where
            value = S.index ts tapePos
            nextPos = codePos + 1
            execNext = execCode tapePos ts nextPos

            updatePos f = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos
            updateVal f = execCode (f tapePos) ts nextPos
            branch cond dir = if cond value then execCode tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1) else execNext
```

Here is complete final source:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Array
import Data.List

mkCache cs mapAccumX bracketPush bracketPop = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumX f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) 
        | c == bracketPush = (i : l, Nothing)
        | c == bracketPop = (tail l, Just $ head l)
        | otherwise = (l, Nothing)

cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error "oops!"
    Just idx -> idx

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = execCode 0 ts 0 where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode _ _ codePos | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
    execCode tapePos ts codePos = case cs ! codePos of
        '+' -> updatePos succ
        '-' -> updatePos pred
        '>' -> updateVal succ
        '<' -> updateVal pred
        '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
        ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
        '.' -> putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execNext
        ',' -> do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode tapePos newTape nextPos }
        _ -> execNext
        where
            value = S.index ts tapePos
            nextPos = codePos + 1
            execNext = execCode tapePos ts nextPos

            updatePos f = execCode tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos
            updateVal f = execCode (f tapePos) ts nextPos
            branch cond dir = if cond value then execCode tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1) else execNext


tape = S.fromList $ replicate 30000 0

csFromString file = listArray (0, length file - 1) file

main = readFile "example.bf" >>= execCode' tape . csFromString
```

Note that my suggestions about `monad-loops`, `lens` and `State` are still to be applied.

The first step is to declare a datatype for our future state.

```
data M = M
    { _tapePos :: Int
    , _tape :: S.Seq Int 
    , _codePos :: Int
    }
```

and make inner `execCode` accept a single parameter.

```
    execCode :: M -> IO ()      
    execCode (M _ _ codePos) | codePos == (snd . bounds $ cs) = return ()
    execCode (M tapePos ts codePos) = case cs ! codePos of
        '+' -> updatePos succ
        '-' -> updatePos pred
        '>' -> updateVal succ
        '<' -> updateVal pred
        '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
        ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
        '.' -> putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos] >> execNext
        ',' -> do { c <- getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in execCode (M tapePos newTape nextPos) }
        _ -> execNext
        where
            value = S.index ts tapePos
            nextPos = codePos + 1
            execNext = execCode (M tapePos ts nextPos)

            updatePos f = execCode (M tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos)
            updateVal f = execCode (M (f tapePos) ts nextPos)
            branch cond dir = if cond value then execCode (M tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1)) else execNext
```

`M` stands for machine state :) and underscores are signals to `Data.Lens.TH` template Haskell code we will start using a bit later.

We will need a state monad transformer ran on top of `IO` monad. Let's declare the type of our monad stack:

```
type ExecT a = StateT M IO a
```

Our future execCode'' will be of type `ExecT ()` instead of current `M -> IO ()`. To execute it and discard the state (as we do now) we'll use `evalStateT`:

```
execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode'' (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode'' :: ExecT ()
    execCode'' = do
        s <- get 
        lift (execCode s)

    execCode :: M -> IO ()
    execCode = ... -- unchanged
```

Now `execCode''` is just a wrapper around our old inner `execCode`. And we fix `execCode` so it can be called directly. Note that we should do the following:

- `lift` all `IO`
- Replace recursive calls `execCode (M ...)` with `put (M ...) >> execCode`
- move `where` statements around so `M tapePos ts codePos` is in scope
- replace old termination guard with `when`

Here is the result:

```
execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode :: ExecT ()
    execCode = do
        M tapePos ts codePos <- get
        let value = S.index ts tapePos
        let nextPos = codePos + 1
        let execNext = put (M tapePos ts nextPos) >> execCode
        let updatePos f = put (M tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos) >> execCode 
        let updateVal f = put (M (f tapePos) ts nextPos) >> execCode
        let branch cond dir = if cond value then put (M tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1)) >> execCode else execNext

        when (codePos /= (snd . bounds $ cs)) $ case cs ! codePos of
            '+' -> updatePos succ
            '-' -> updatePos pred
            '>' -> updateVal succ
            '<' -> updateVal pred
            '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
            ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
            '.' -> lift (putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos]) >> execNext
            ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in put (M tapePos newTape nextPos) >> execCode } 
            _ -> execNext
```

Now note that all branches of `case` end in `>> execCode`. So it can be moved around to form a nice `while` control structure:

```
execCode :: ExecT ()
execCode = do
    M tapePos ts codePos <- get
    let value = S.index ts tapePos
    let nextPos = codePos + 1
    let execNext = put (M tapePos ts nextPos)
    let updatePos f = put (M tapePos (S.update tapePos (f value) ts) nextPos) 
    let updateVal f = put (M (f tapePos) ts nextPos)
    let branch cond dir = if cond value then put (M tapePos ts (cache dir codePos + 1)) else execNext

    when (codePos /= (snd . bounds $ cs)) $ do
        case cs ! codePos of
            '+' -> updatePos succ
            '-' -> updatePos pred
            '>' -> updateVal succ
            '<' -> updateVal pred
            '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
            ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
            '.' -> lift (putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos]) >> execNext
            ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; let newTape = S.update tapePos (ord c) ts in put (M tapePos newTape nextPos) } 
            _ -> execNext
        execCode
```

Now it's finally time for `lens` to shine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell  #-}
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative

...

data M = M
    { _mTapePos :: Int
    , _mTape :: S.Seq Int 
    , _mCodePos :: Int
    }

$(makeLenses ''M)

type ExecT a = StateT M IO a

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode :: ExecT ()
    execCode = do
        M tapePos ts codePos <- get
        let value = S.index ts tapePos
        let nextPos = codePos + 1
        let execNext = mCodePos += 1
        let updatePos f = mTape %= S.update tapePos (f value) >> execNext 
        let updateVal f = mTapePos %= f >> execNext
        let branch cond dir = if cond value then mCodePos %= succ . cache dir else execNext

        when (codePos /= (snd . bounds $ cs)) $ do
            case cs ! codePos of
                '+' -> updatePos succ
                '-' -> updatePos pred
                '>' -> updateVal succ
                '<' -> updateVal pred
                '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
                ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
                '.' -> lift (putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos]) >> execNext
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTape %= S.update tapePos (ord c) >> execNext } 
                _ -> execNext
            execCode
```

I did the following:

- Added imports and TemplateHaskell pragma
- Added a template Haskell call to generate definitions for `mTapePos` from `_mTapePos`
- replaced all `put` calls with one or many lens-based state modifiers, joined by `>>`. E.g. if 2 fields of `M` are modified I chain 2 modifiers. If just 1 - no need to chain. Basically it's just `>> execNext` instead of `nextPos`.
- removed unused `nextPos`

Now it turns out that `branch` has its own hidden `execNext` (note `succ .` in the code above):

```
let branch cond dir = if cond value then mCodePos %= cache dir >> execNext else execNext
```

So we can transform it to `when` easily:

```
let branch cond dir = when (cond value) (mCodePos %= cache dir) >> execNext
```

And now it turns out that `>> execNext` is everywhere. We can move it after `case` and  inline:

```
execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode :: ExecT ()
    execCode = do
        M tapePos ts codePos <- get
        let value = S.index ts tapePos
        let updatePos f = mTape %= S.update tapePos (f value) 
        let updateVal f = mTapePos %= f
        let branch cond dir = when (cond value) (mCodePos %= cache dir)

        when (codePos /= (snd . bounds $ cs)) $ do
            case cs ! codePos of
                '+' -> updatePos succ
                '-' -> updatePos pred
                '>' -> updateVal succ
                '<' -> updateVal pred
                '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
                ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
                '.' -> lift (putStr [chr $ S.index ts tapePos])
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTape %= S.update tapePos (ord c) } 
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            execCode
```

After some more cleanup we get:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell  #-}
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative

import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Control.Monad.State

mkCache cs mapAccumX bracketPush bracketPop = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumX f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) 
        | c == bracketPush = (i : l, Nothing)
        | c == bracketPop = (tail l, Just $ head l)
        | otherwise = (l, Nothing)

cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error "oops!"
    Just idx -> idx

data M = M
    { _mTapePos :: Int
    , _mTape :: S.Seq Int 
    , _mCodePos :: Int
    }

$(makeLenses ''M)

type ExecT a = StateT M IO a

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode :: ExecT ()
    execCode = do
        M tapePos ts codePos <- get
        let value = S.index ts tapePos
        let tapeAtPos = mTape . ix tapePos
        let branch cond dir = when (cond value) (mCodePos %= cache dir)

        when (codePos /= (snd . bounds $ cs)) $ do
            case cs ! codePos of
                '+' -> tapeAtPos += 1 
                '-' -> tapeAtPos -= 1
                '>' -> mTapePos += 1
                '<' -> mTapePos -= 1
                '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
                ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
                '.' -> lift (putChar $ chr value)
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTape %= S.update tapePos (ord c) } 
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            execCode

tape = S.fromList $ replicate 30000 0

csFromString file = listArray (0, length file - 1) file

main = readFile "example.bf" >>= execCode' tape . csFromString
```

One more iteration of tuning for `execCode'` to make code more uniform which is good for readability and maintenance:

- `tapeAtPos` is made a self-contained compound lens, without reliance on `tapePos` and
- `tapeAtPos` is moved out of `execState'` body to global scope, and renamed to `mTapeAtPos` uniformly with other lenses
- `value` is renamed `tapeAtPos` as it corresponds to `mTapeAtPos`
- `mTapeAtPos` is used uniformly for both getting and updating the value everywhere including the `getChar` branch
- `unsafeUse` helper is used to get `tapeAtPos` uniformly with `codePos`. It is called unsafe because `tapeAtPos` may fail if `mTapePos` is out of range!
- lens API is used to read code uniformly with reading tape
- extra parenthesis/`$` are removed from `when` condition
- `M ... <- get` is removed as it is not used anymore

The code:

```
mTapeAtPos f m = (mTape . ix (m ^. mTapePos)) f m

unsafeUse traversal = (^?! traversal) <$> get

execCode' :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode' ts cs = evalStateT execCode (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    execCode :: ExecT ()
    execCode = do
        tapeAtPos <- unsafeUse mTapeAtPos 
        codePos <- use mCodePos
        let branch cond dir = when (cond tapeAtPos) (mCodePos %= cache dir)
        when (codePos /= snd (bounds cs)) $ do
            case cs ^?! ix codePos of
                '+' -> mTapeAtPos += 1 
                '-' -> mTapeAtPos -= 1
                '>' -> mTapePos += 1
                '<' -> mTapePos -= 1
                '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
                ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
                '.' -> lift (putChar $ chr tapeAtPos)
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTapeAtPos .= ord c } 
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            execCode
```

It can be made even more uniform:

- at this point `tapePos` is used only in `branch` it can be moved into `branch`
- `branch` then can be moved outside of `execCode` as it doesn't a closure any more
- it seems inner `execCode` is better named `loop`, and `ExecT` is `LoopStateT`

The code:

```
branch cond dir = do 
    tapeAtPos <- unsafeUse mTapeAtPos 
    when (cond tapeAtPos) (mCodePos %= cache dir)

execCode :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode ts cs = evalStateT loop (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['



    loop :: LoopStateT ()
    loop = do
        codePos <- use mCodePos
        when (codePos /= snd (bounds cs)) $ do
            case cs ^?! ix codePos of
                '+' -> mTapeAtPos += 1 
                '-' -> mTapeAtPos -= 1
                '>' -> mTapePos += 1
                '<' -> mTapePos -= 1
                '[' -> branch (== 0) next 
                ']' -> branch (/= 0) prev
                '.' -> unsafeUse mTapePos >>= lift . putChar . chr
                ',' -> lift (ord <$> getChar) >>= (mTapeAtPos .=)
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            loop
```

At this point it seems `branch` and `./,` symmetry aren't worth it, so I inlined `branch`, reverted `getChar` branch to use do-notation and moved `tapeAtPos <-` to the top of `loop`:

```
    loop :: LoopStateT ()
    loop = do
        tapeAtPos <- unsafeUse mTapeAtPos
        codePos <- use mCodePos
        when (codePos /= snd (bounds cs)) $ do
            case cs ^?! ix codePos of
                '+' -> mTapeAtPos += 1 
                '-' -> mTapeAtPos -= 1
                '>' -> mTapePos += 1
                '<' -> mTapePos -= 1
                '[' -> when (tapeAtPos == 0) (mCodePos %= cache next)
                ']' -> when (tapeAtPos /= 0) (mCodePos %= cache prev)
                '.' -> lift $ putChar (chr tapeAtPos)
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTapeAtPos .= ord c }
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            loop
```

Another improvement is better diagnostics of match failures in `cache`:

```
cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error $ "No matching bracket at offset " ++ show i
    Just idx -> idx
```

So we get:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell  #-}
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative

import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Array
import Data.List (mapAccumR, mapAccumL)
import Control.Monad.State (lift, get, evalStateT, when, StateT(..))

mkCache cs mapAccumX bracketPush bracketPop = listArray (bounds cs) $ snd $ mapAccumX f [] $ assocs cs where
    f l (i, c) 
        | c == bracketPush = (i : l, Nothing)
        | c == bracketPop = (tail l, Just $ head l)
        | otherwise = (l, Nothing)

cache arr i = case arr ! i of
    Nothing -> error $ "No matching bracket at offset " ++ show i
    Just idx -> idx

data M = M
    { _mTapePos :: Int
    , _mTape :: S.Seq Int 
    , _mCodePos :: Int
    }

$(makeLenses ''M)

type LoopStateT a = StateT M IO a

mTapeAtPos f m = (mTape . ix (m ^. mTapePos)) f m

unsafeUse traversal = (^?! traversal) <$> get

execCode :: S.Seq Int -> Array Int Char -> IO ()
execCode ts cs = evalStateT loop (M 0 ts 0) where
    prev = mkCache cs mapAccumL '[' ']'
    next = mkCache cs mapAccumR ']' '['

    loop :: LoopStateT ()
    loop = do
        tapeAtPos <- unsafeUse mTapeAtPos
        codePos <- use mCodePos
        when (codePos /= snd (bounds cs)) $ do
            case cs ^?! ix codePos of
                '+' -> mTapeAtPos += 1 
                '-' -> mTapeAtPos -= 1
                '>' -> mTapePos += 1
                '<' -> mTapePos -= 1
                '[' -> when (tapeAtPos == 0) (mCodePos %= cache next)
                ']' -> when (tapeAtPos /= 0) (mCodePos %= cache prev)
                '.' -> lift $ putChar $ chr tapeAtPos
                ',' -> do { c <- lift getChar; mTapeAtPos .= ord c }
                _ -> return ()
            mCodePos += 1
            loop

tape = S.fromList $ replicate 30000 0

csFromString file = listArray (0, length file - 1) file

main = readFile "example.bf" >>= execCode tape . csFromString
```

Comment: Hey I just realized you replied to this because I had break from school. I think I lost the original account I posted this under. I just wanted to thank you for such a long and comprehensive reply. A lot of it is over my head but I will continue to reference this for years probably while I learn Haskell further.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that this interpreter works, having tried it on two [ASCII table printers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/26648/9357) and a [FizzBuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57382/9357), and finding that both failed to loop at all.  [Hello World!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Hello_World.21) worked, though.

For one thing, it appears that `execCode` terminates prematurely: it ends before executing the last instruction in the program, not after.

Brainfuck typically has a tape whose values [wrap modulo 256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Cell_size) (though there are also dialects with larger cells).  Your cell size is just the range of the Haskell `Int` type, which is guaranteed to hold at least -2<sup>29</sup> ≤ `Int` ≤ 2<sup>29</sup> - 1, but may have a larger range.  Those bounds don't guarantee to any of the common Brainfuck cell sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Made some changes and those two examples seem to work now. Let me know if there's anything else. Conway's game of life seems to work too after checking.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Isn't it a waste of time to have multiple people suggest the same thing and spot the same errors? All I need to change is an `==` to `>` to make those two listed programs work.

Comment: Future reviewers would probably read existing answers before writing an answer. On the other hand, fixing the code in the question in response to an answer invalidates the answer. It's like asking for help, then saying "never mind, I fixed it."

Comment: The right way to do is to put both original and final versions of the code. Changing original code in place isn't good.

Comment: @nponeccop As noted on the Meta post, in our experience, allowing edits, addenda, and errata in questions leads to confusion about what code is to be reviewed.